# How can I get related product images as slider in modal,on product view page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I want to get all product images in modal for slider. So that if product view modal is opened, the it should contain all images to swipe.(on product view page)

```
<?php $items = $this->getItems();?>
<?php $thumbnails = $this->getGalleryImages();?>


<div class="container slick-modal-block">
    <ol class="related-product-list shop-related-slick">
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <li class="related-product-list_item media">
                <div class="pdp-grid">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <div class="pdp-media">
                            <?php if (count($thumbnails) > 0): ?>
                                <?php
                                // GravDept:
                                $photoswipeIndex = 0;
                                ?>
                                <ul class="thumbnail-list">
                                <?php foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail): ?>
                                    <li class="thumbnail-list_item">
                                        <a
                                        class="product-image thumbnail-list_link"
                                        href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image', $thumbnail->getFile()); ?>"
                                        title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>"data-photoswipe-index="<?php echo $photoswipeIndex; ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $thumbnail->getFile())->resize(60); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>">
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php $photoswipeIndex++; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
<div class="container slick-modal-block">
    <ol class="related-product-list shop-related-slick">
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <li class="related-product-list_item media">
                <div class="pdp-grid">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <div class="pdp-media">
                        <?php 
                            $tmpProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($item->getId());
                            $thumbnails = $tmpProduct->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
                            <?php if (count($thumbnails) > 0): ?>
                                <?php
                                // GravDept:
                                $photoswipeIndex = 0;
                                ?>
                                <ul class="thumbnail-list">
                                <?php foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail): ?>
                                    <li class="thumbnail-list_item">
                                        <a
                                        class="product-image thumbnail-list_link"
                                        href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image', $thumbnail->getFile()); ?>"
                                        title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>"data-photoswipe-index="<?php echo $photoswipeIndex; ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $thumbnail->getFile())->resize(60); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($thumbnail->getLabel()); ?>">
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php $photoswipeIndex++; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: but get model in for each is not good practice :(
Please update!ASAP

Comment: @SushantThorat, It is required to load a product because in related product block, there is no images detail available. To get all images, you must create object of a product and then you can get its related images.